# ¿Por que me sale el siguiente error al intentar subir un archivo a mi base de datos en MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

lo que trato de hacer es subir un archivo con GridFS desde PHP a MongoDB, pero me sale el siguiente error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Database::selectGridFS() in C:\xampp\htdocs\actividadmo\subir.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\actividadmo\subir.php on line 16

Mi código es:

```
<?php

//buscas el directorio donde guardar`introducir el código aquí`
    $dir="files/";
    opendir($dir);
//pasas el archivo a carga que va dirigirla al directorio de la carpeta 
    $carga=$dir.basename($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
    copy($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],$carga);

    echo"Archvo cargado exitosamente";

    $nombre=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];


    require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Composer
    $gridfs = (new MongoDB\Client)->CECAR->selectGridFS();;

    $filename =$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $filetype =$_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tmpfilepath =$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $dec =$_POST['desc'];


    $gridfs->storeFile( $carga,  array('filename'=>$filename,'filetype','desc'=>$dec));
 
   
    
?>
```

Comment: Según la [doc. de MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/tutorial/gridfs/) el método es: **`selectGridFSBucket`**

Comment: Ya intente y me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Pareciera que no te estuviese cargando correctamente la libreria de MongoDB estas seguro que tienes bien tu estructura de archivos configurados en el autoload.php?

Comment: Si señor, de echo lo agregue con composser

Comment: ¿Qué versión del controlador estás usando?

Comment: ya logré que me salga en la base de datos, sin embargo en fs.chunks no me salen los datos y en fs.files si, pero en lengh me sale vacio